# how can i format my hard drive and reinstall a newer version of ubuntu im currently using 14.03i have a [32gbflashdrive]

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

i have a lenovo g580 it had win 8 pre installed but because of the annoying constant updates from microsoft and my interests in linux i decided to install ubuntu alongside windows 8. before i installed it i created a partition it was where i wanted ubuntu to originally be installed , the amount of memory on that partition is half my harddrives memory my hard disk is a hitatchi 320gb drive so now i have 68 gb of unused space and my ubuntu has 136gb and there are other drives with more free space so im thinkin of formating my disk completely and installing ubuntu from a flash drive is it possable?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to start a new with a newer version of ubuntu you can use either a USB or CD with enough space for the requirments after going into your installation process once you see the option to install along side with your old version you can either click erase disk and install the latest version or you can hit somthing else which will bring up the partition editor hit change on your currently used partition and hit format and set the partition settings like the example below

ext4 journal
primary
mount /

making a swap is optional

with the format button ticked it will format and have your new partition ready to use for the latest edition